# Creating hidden Character in java applications

Tags: java, passwords

Im Trying to put something in case 1 in the switch that when i add the  new pin code it will display "*" rather than the actual number

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public Main() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

         int userChoice;
         boolean quit = false;
         System.out.println("Welcome to GNBanking");
         System.out.println("Please Create Your Account");
         String name;
        String add;
        int contact;
        double initialdep;
        int pin;
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 999999 + 1);

        Scanner reg = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Fill out the information below");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
        name = reg.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Address: ");
        add = reg.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Contact Number: ");
        contact = reg.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Initial Deposit");
        initialdep = reg.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Pin: ");
        pin = reg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Congratulations You Are Now A Member Of GNBanking Please Confirm Your Account");


        System.out.println("Name of Member: " +name);
        System.out.println("Address: "+ add);
        System.out.println("Contact Number:" +contact);
        System.out.println("Initial Deposit: "+initialdep);
        System.out.println("Pin " + pin);
        System.out.println("Is the Information Accurate? Y/N ");
        String choice =reg.next();
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
             System.out.println("Excellent!!");
             System.out.println("Your Account Number is: "+ random );
             System.out.println("Name of Member: " +name);
             System.out.println("Address: "+ add);
             System.out.println("Contact Number:" +contact);
             System.out.println("Initial Deposit: "+initialdep);
             System.out.println("Pin: " + pin);
         }else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                System.out.println("Do You Want to try again? Y/N");
             String secchoi = reg.next();
            if(secchoi.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
             main (null);
             }else if (secchoi.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                 System.out.println("Have A Nice Day!");
             }


    }    
         do {
               System.out.println("[1] Change Pincode");
               System.out.println("[2] View Balance");
               System.out.println("[3] Deposit Money");
               System.out.println("[4] Withdraw ");
               System.out.println("[5] Close Account");
               userChoice = in.nextInt();
               switch (userChoice) {
               case 1:
                  // Here Im trying to create a change pin that wont show the int but rather the character "*" when I type 
                     break;
               case 2:
                     // View Balance 
                     break;
               case 3:
                     // Deposit
                     break;
               case 4:
                     // Withdraw
                     break;
               case 5:
                   quit = true;
                   break;
               default:
                     System.out.println("Wrong choice.");
                     break;
               }
               System.out.println();
         } while (!quit);
         System.out.println("Have A Nice Day");


    }

}
*/
```

Comment: Why did you tag JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in the programm, If you want to display it after taking input.

```
    int value=1234567780; //Your pincode
    String data=String.valueOf(value).replaceAll("[0-9]", "*"); //replacing and storing it into new String variable
    System.out.println(data);
```

This one you can use while taking inputs from the user in password format.

```
System.out.println("Please Enter your pincode: ");

char[] pinCode= cosole.readPassword();
String data = new String(pinCode);
```

**NOTE:** The `cosole.readPassword()` may not work in IDE , You have to run the programm through console.

Comment: i was thinking of something more simple like 
System.out.println("Enter New Pin:");
               pin = reg.nextInt();

Comment: you want this at input level or output level while displaying it?